# Convert String into exact same Int

Tags: parsing, go

How can i convert string into integer without removing the 0 digit prefix from start. Use case like this i have a string like "0093" and i want to convert same as 0093 in integer. I try strconv but problem is this package remove 00 prefix from 0093 after conversion. can any one have better solution for this problem.

```
s := "0093"
  if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s); err == nil {
  fmt.Printf("i=%d, type: %T\n", i, i)
}
```

output is 93 but i want exact 0093 in int type.

Comment: How you decide how many zeros should lead? Why `0093` and not `00930000000` or `0000000930000000`?

Comment: i need integer in four digits from 0 to 9999. So if got 93 i format it into 0093 string and now i want to this string exact as 0093 in type integer.

Comment: You have misunderstand what is integer.

Comment: So there is no use case for this in type integer?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 0-leading integer. However, you _can_ output an integer with leading zeros. But the integer of value 093 is identical to the integer of value 93.

Comment: thank you i was looking a solution to get this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for the `fmt` package:

```
Width is specified by an optional decimal number immediately preceding the verb. If absent, the width is whatever is necessary to represent the value.
...
Other flags: 
0   pad with leading zeros rather than spaces;
    for numbers, this moves the padding after the sign
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

If you combine these two things then you get the code:

```
fmt.Printf("i=%04d, type: %T\n", i, i)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lR77KoCswv_B